# file operations in java

Tags: java, file, operations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can I import a file in java programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176869/how-can-i-import-a-file-in-java-programming-language)

How can we read and write a file in java? What are the basic operations to do this?

Comment: do some work searching before asking a question like this. Search engines are your friend.

Comment: it also looks like you asked the exact same question already and got some nice links that give you EXACTLY what you need to do this

Comment: Rather than submitting a new question, you should have responded to the comments on your previous question and edited it.

Answer (score 2):

[Reading and writing text files in Java](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42)